# Unable to pass variables in Jenkins Pipeline Post Stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

> `````
> Scenario: I am unable to pass parameter in post stage step . getting below error  ```` 
>   post {  
>      success {            script {
>          sh """
>          count=`ca changes.txt | wc -l`
>          echo ${count}
>          if [[ ${count} == 0 ]]; then
>               echo 'condition success'  
>           else
>               echo 'condition not success'
>           fi
>           """
>      }  
>
>     } ```
> `````
>
> > error:
> >
> > 16:24:38 [email-2] Running shell script
> >              16:24:39 ++ cat changes.txt
> >              16:24:39 ++ wc -l
> >              16:24:39 + count=7
> >              [Pipeline] }
> >              [Pipeline] // script
> >              Error when executing success post condition:
> >              groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $count for class: WorkflowScript
> >              at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)

Comment: It appears that you are trying to interpret `count` as a shell variable according to your logic, but as a Jenkins variable by your syntax. Either convert your shell to Groovy, or escape the variable so it is interpreted as shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                       echo "1" > changes.txt
                       count=\$(cat changes.txt | wc -l)
                       echo \$count
                       if [ \$count = 0 ]; then
                            echo 'condition success'  
                       else
                            echo 'condition not success'
                       fi
                       """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on jenkins in /home/user/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 1
+ cat changes.txt
+ wc -l
+ count=1
+ echo 1
1
+ [ 1 = 0 ]
+ echo condition not success
condition not success
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: thanks for quick help . getting error : tried with "\\" but no luck Error:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/cg/root/7911142/main.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 7.
   count=\$(wc -l changes.txt)

Comment: But when trying to access same variable ( out side sh block ) not getting any value . echo \$count or echo sh ''echo${count}" , but no luck . Can you please help me on this.

Comment: The `count` variable is a `bash` variable, it was created inside the script and stopped existing at the end of the `sh` block. It's not a Groovy variable.

Comment: could you please guide me how to get value as i need to use in Jenkins other stage.